# JQuery: Real-time search - no div autoupdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, get

Now I'm trying to write script for real-time search. Here the problem: script work just once, then div is not updating. My concept: catch keypress in search form, and put result in div every time, when any key was pressed.

```
              <script>

                $(document).ready(function(){
                var poisk_val = $('#poisk').val();
                function sendAjaxGET(_data,_url){
                    $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:_url,
            data:_data,
            cache:false
                    });
                }
function AjaxResultat(_data,_blres,_divname,_url){
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:_url,
            data:_data,
            cache:true,
            success:function(resultat){
                $('.info_'+_blres).html(resultat).show();
                $('#backgroundPopup').fadeIn(500);
                $(_divname).fadeIn(500);
                $('body').bind("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.which === 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
          $(_divname).fadeOut(500);
          $('#backgroundPopup').fadeOut(500);  // function close pop up
       }
           });
                $('.close').click(function() {
    $(_divname).fadeOut(500);
    $('#backgroundPopup').fadeOut(500);
    });
    $(".close").hover(
                    function() {
                        $('span.ecs_tooltip').fadeIn(500);
                    },
                    function () {
                        $('span.ecs_tooltip').fadeOut(500);
                    }
                );

            }

    });
    return false;
    }
                function genSecurityID(){
                //    eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(c/a))+String.fromCharCode(c%a+161)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\[\xa1-\xff]+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp(e(c),'g'),k[c])}}return p}('m=¡(m);n=¡(n);£ ¢.¤(¢.¥()*(n-m+1))+m;',5,5,'parseInt|Math|return|floor|random'.split('|'),0,{}))
m = +(+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]+[+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]]]]]]]]);
n = +(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]]]]]]]]);
return Math[(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]( Math[(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]]() * (n - m + +!+[]) ) + m;
}
                var securityID = genSecurityID();


        $('#poisk').keydown(function(){ 
                    var data = {'search':poisk_val, '_':securityID};
                    AjaxResultat(data,'search','.search_res','?view=live_search');
                    alert(data);
                });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Put it in a jsfiddle for easier debugging.

Comment: @user145400 No problem! http://jsfiddle.net/h6f8xqwz/

Comment: Kirill, you just copied the JS from here into a jsfiddle.. We'll need some HTML elements in there so that the problem can be demonstrated.

Comment: please only post relevant code and format it so it is readable

Comment: there are so many HTML that I need to send to you, sorry, but I give you link to original site, that I making. I think, script can't get value from the form. http://176.114.3.55